# Changing default column names in R data.table aggregations

Tags: r, data.table

When in interactive mode, exploring aggregations in data.table, I may do dozens, or hundreds of experiments.  The default column names after aggregations (`V1`, `V2`, etc) obviously aren't very informative, after writing the minimal amount of code needed to generate the aggregations.  Often, I'd be happier with the default column name of a simple aggregation of one column, like a mean or sum, to be just the name of the underlying variable.

All the extra column name typing gets tiring, and I want to avoid this.

Is there any easy way to do this in `data.table`?

e.g. a simplified example to demonstrate if it's not clear:

```
DT = data.table(x =rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y_a_long_name=c(1,3,6), v_a_long_name=1:9)

DT[, .(sum(v_a_long_name), mean(y_a_long_name)), by = x]
#    x V1       V2
# 1: b  6 3.333333
# 2: a 15 3.333333
# 3: c 24 3.333333
```

When you start working with several columns, using different aggregation type functions, the above labeling, `V1`, `V2`, isn't helpful.

All the extra typing of repeating the names is tedious, but I'd like to see something like this:

```
DT[, .(v_a_long_name = sum(v_a_long_name), y_a_long_name = mean(y_a_long_name)), by = x]
#    x v_a_long_name y_a_long_name
# 1: b             6      3.333333
# 2: a            15      3.333333
# 3: c            24      3.333333
```

while typing as minimal as possible.  e.g. it would be ideal if

```
DT[, .(sum(v_a_long_name), mean(y_a_long_name)), by = x]
```

printed this by default:

```
#    x v_a_long_name y_a_long_name
# 1: b             6      3.333333
# 2: a            15      3.333333
# 3: c            24      3.333333
```

Comment: The answers below will stop `GForce` from optimizing your queries. Does your IDE not have auto-complete? If you're just playing around, I don't see much penalty to using names like `V1`, `V5`. If this is not ephemeral, writing explicit code will help others (including future-you) better understand your code. Choosing to eliminate `sum` and `mean` from the name of the aggregated variable strikes me as troublesome / begging for confusion/errors down the line.

Comment: With that in mind, there are a few outstanding issues related to auto-naming columns: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1604, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/618, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543, and probably most germane: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1227

Comment: Feel free to chime in on those issues. I don't think it makes any sense for auto-naming to exclude the _method_ of aggregation (i.e. any solution I'd find acceptable would be like `v_a_long_name_sum` and `y_a_long_name_mean`)

Comment: Yeah, automating including method would be even better (just more typing).  Yes, most of the time the code would be kept long term, so auto naming would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a roundabout solution, but you can pass a list of functions and a list of columns to `Map` + `do.call`. The names for the resulting columns will be taken from the first argument to `Map`, which means you only have to specify the names in long-form in `.SDcols` once:

```
DT[, 
  Map(do.call, args=lapply(.SD,list), what=c(sum,mean)),
  by=x, .SDcols=c("v_a_long_name","y_a_long_name")
]

#   x v_a_long_name y_a_long_name
#1: b             6      3.333333
#2: a            15      3.333333
#3: c            24      3.333333
```

If the auto-naming is required, you could define the variables ahead of time:

```
nms  <- c("v_a_long_name","y_a_long_name")
funs <- c("sum","mean")

DT[, 
  setNames(Map(do.call, args=lapply(.SD,list), what=funs), paste(nms,funs,sep="_")),
  by=x, .SDcols=nms
]

#   x v_a_long_name_sum y_a_long_name_mean
#1: b                 6           3.333333
#2: a                15           3.333333
#3: c                24           3.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `setNames` to wrap around the `list` of columns

```
DT[, setNames(.(sum(v_a_long_name), mean(y_a_long_name)), names(DT)[2:3]), by = x]
#   x y_a_long_name v_a_long_name
#1: b             6      3.333333
#2: a            15      3.333333
#3: c            24      3.333333
```

---

Or with `setnames` after getting the output

```
setnames(DT[, .(sum(v_a_long_name), mean(y_a_long_name)),
                         by = x], 2:3, names(DT)[2:3])[]
```

---

Or make it more compact by extracting the columns from `.SD`

```
setnames(DT[, .(sum(.SD[[2]]), mean(.SD[[1]])), by = x], 2:3, names(DT)[2:3])[]
```

Comment: @QuantitativeMelancholy  Sorry, thanks for the input.  You don't need the full column names, but can index with `setnames` to assign.  updated

Comment: I like this approach, though it is still more typing and thinking to select the right columns etc when it's a big data.table. would be nice if there was some default option that returns the name of a column after applying some function to it.

Comment: @QuantitativeMelancholy  You can use `get` with names